# Could not determine type for: java.util.Map: JPA2 Map annotation

Tags: jpa, dictionary, mapping

I use JPA in standalone mode. I have this error when i launch the persistenceManager:
factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);

I have test several work around grabbed around the net... no success.
Can you give me some clues ?

Could not determine type for: java.util.Map..................
for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(initRegisters)]

I have configured my mapping like this:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = Integer.class)
@MapKeyClass(InitRegister.class)
private Map<Integer, InitRegister> initRegisters = new HashMap<>();
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Thx in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution Found:

Actually, all change was done on the declaration. I tried to add annotation on the getters field and..... it works.

Don't know why. I know that is a good practice but not mandatory.

Prob solved.

Answer (score 3):

`targetClass` attribute of `ElementCollection` when applied to a map, refers to the type of the Map value - in your case, this is the `InitRegister`

On the other hand, `@MapKeyClass` refers to the type of the Map key, which is an `Integer` type.

So to fix your mistake, you just switch the types:

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = InitRegister.class)
@MapKeyClass(Integer.class)
private Map<Integer, InitRegister> initRegisters;
```

You need not specify the `targetClass` and `MapKeyClass` if you are using generics.

So this one should be fine as well:

```
@ElementCollection
private Map<Integer, InitRegister> initRegisters;
```

Also, keep in mind that `@ElementCollection` is used only for basic types and embeddable types. If your `InitRegister` class happens to be an entity type, then you should not use `@ElementCollection`. You should use collection valued relationship mappings, either `@OneToMany` or `@ManyToMany`.

Comment: What do you mean by "entity class" ? Class anotated by entity ? because, yes, InitRegister, is an entity class. Not embeddable, and actually, it inherite a super class.

Comment: Yes, entity class is class annotated with @Entity